# Intermittent unknown modifier error with php regex

Tags: php, regex

I'm using regex to copy the margin CSS used in @page to body. For most HTML pages the code replacement works well.

However on some pages I get an unknown modifier error and I can't determine where the issue is with the regex.

Any guidance on how to resolve this error would be much appreciated.

Error: Message: preg_replace() [function.preg-replace]: Unknown modifier ';'

Code excerpt:

```
    $pattern ='%@page \{.*?\}%s';
    preg_match($pattern, $output, $page);

    $pattern = '%margin:.*?\;%s';
    preg_match($pattern, $page[0], $margin);

    $pattern = '%(?=body).*?\}%s';
    preg_match($pattern, $output, $body);


    $new_margin = $margin[0] . "\n" . "}";
    $new_body = preg_replace("%\}%", $new_margin, $body[0]);

    $output = preg_replace('%'.$body[0].'%', $new_body, $output); //ERROR HERE
```

$body[0]:

```
body { font-family: 'Josefin Slab', sans-serif; font-size: 9pt;  height: 100%; min-height: 100%; display:block; }
```

$new_body:

```
body { font-family: 'Josefin Slab', sans-serif; font-size: 9pt;  height: 100%; min-height: 100%; display:block; margin: .7in .3in .3in .4in; }
```

Comment: Does the error disappear if you escape all the the backslashes in the pattern string? I.e. use `'%margin:.*?\\;%s'`

Comment: I had tried that. I added the first backslash anyway to escape the ;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could call [`preg_quote($body[0], '%')`](http://us.php.net/preg_quote) before putting it into `preg_replace`. Someone else had posted this answer just minutes earlier, but it seems to be gone now.

Edit 2: preg_quote actually can work, as pointed out below by ridgerunner.

Since you are not using any metacharacters, it might be easier to just use `str_replace` instead of `preg_replace`?

Comment: Thx. Tried preg_quote on it with no luck, but going to try your str_replace idea.

Comment: str_replace did it: `$output = str_replace($body[0], $new_body, $output);`

Comment: `preg_quote($body[0], '%')` will do the trick correctly, but you need to supply the `'%'` as the optional second argument.